# Categorical semantics of Boolean type

Tags: logic, category-theory, type-theory

I have a (hopefully) quick question about the interpretation of the Boolean type $\mathbf{2}$ (consisting of two objects $\mathbf{True}$ and $\mathbf{False}$) in a categorical model $\mathscr{C}$ of Martin-Löf dependent type theory. A natural guess to me is that this should be interpreted as the coproduct $$1\coprod 1$$ where $1$ denotes the terminal object in $\mathscr{C}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right.

Comment: Depending on what you want $2$ to do, a subobject classifier is often what you want, rather than $1\sqcup 1$.

Comment: @KevinCarlson They are the same in Boolean toposes, but this is too restrictive. I thought that the subobject classifier models the type of mere propositions in HoTT.  Further, on page 130 of the article http://www.math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/synthetic.pdf, the authors seem to define the Boolean type as the binary sum $\mathbf{1} + \mathbf{1}$, which seems to suggest a coproduct interpretation.

Comment: @CuriousKid7 yeah, this is right if you literally just want "true" and "false." The subobject classifier can be interpreted equally as the type of all truth values, which is often more important.

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/finite+object#ExternalDefinition
I think in dependent type theory you might interpret that as $\Sigma n: \mathbb{N}, n < 2$? Which should be the same thing in a topos or most categories.